# Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 200, 200, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I've just started to learn Tensorflow (2.1.0) and Keras (2.3.7) with Python 3.7.7.

I have this network:

```
def vgg16(input_size = (224,224,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size, name='input')

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_2')(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_3')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_2')(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_3')(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_2')(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_3')(conv5)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_5')(conv5)    
    flatten = Flatten(name = 'flatten')(pool5)

    dense1 = Dense(units = 4096,activation = "relu", name = 'dense_1')(flatten)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 4096,activation = "relu", name = 'dense_2')(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax", name = 'dense_3')(dense2)

    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = dense3, name ='vgg-16')

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

And this is the code that use it:

```
model = vgg16(input_size=(200, 200, 1))

for episode in range(num_episodes):
    selected = np.random.permutation(no_of_samples)[:num_shot + num_query]
    # Create our Support Set.
    support_set = np.array(D[selected[:num_shot]])
    # Create our Query Set.
    query_set = np.array(D[selected[num_query:]])

    X_train = support_set[:,0,:]
    y_train = support_set[:,1,:]

    X_valid = query_set[:,0,:]
    y_valid = query_set[:,1,:]

    results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=5,
                        validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

`X_train`, `y_train`, `X_valid` and `y_valid` have a this shape: `(5, 200, 200, 1)`.

But I get this error:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but
>   got array with shape (5, 200, 200, 1)

I don't understand why. I have changed the `fit` call removing the `batch_size`:

```
results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

But I get the same error:

How can I fix this error?

Maybe, the problem is that I'm using **one** channel images.

Model summary:

```
Model: "vgg-16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           (None, 200, 200, 1)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      640
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      36928
_________________________________________________________________
pool_1 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 100, 100, 64)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 128)     73856
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 128)     147584
_________________________________________________________________
pool_2 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 50, 50, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 256)       295168
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
pool_3 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 25, 25, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 512)       1180160
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
pool_4 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 12, 12, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
pool_5 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 6, 6, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 18432)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              75501568
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              16781312
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 8194
=================================================================
Total params: 107,004,610
Trainable params: 107,004,610
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for having each layer twice or is it a bad copy-paste?

Comment: what are you trying to predict? the target you're trying to predict seem to be images

Comment: @NicolasGervais Ok, I have found my error: I'm trying to use it to do semantic segmentation. And this network doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your training data has `5`, `(200,200,1)` images, that's correct, but target data (`y`) should be the `5` corresponding labels, with shape `(2,)`. So the shape of `y_train` should be `(5,2)`. Right now they have the wrong shape.

Answer (score 1):

> `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_valid` and `y_valid` have a this shape: `(5, 200, 200,1)`.

According to your network's summary

```
>> vvg16().summary()

Model: "vgg-16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
pool_1 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool_2 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
pool_3 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
pool_4 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_3 (Conv2D)             (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
pool_5 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 8194      
=================================================================
Total params: 134,268,738
Trainable params: 134,268,738
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Your `X_train` and `X_valid` need to have a shape of `(224,224,3)`
Your `y_train` and `y_valid` need to have total `2 classes` and be one-hot encoded due to `keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy`

---

#### Edit:

When the output is an array of *N* classes:

1. last layer should be `Dense(N,"softmax")`
2. the loss should be `keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

When the output is one-hot encoded *N* classes:

1. if not already encoded use `keras.utils.to_categorical(array, N)`
2. last layer should be `Dense(N,"softmax")`
3. the loss should be `keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy`

When the purpose is not to classify:

1. your last layer should produce the same shape
2. you need to use a proper activation
3. you don't need to use flatten
4. check `autoencoder` concept to see how you can produce output that's has the same shape as your input

Comment: No, its input_size is (200, 200, 1). Look at this line: `model = vgg16(input_size=(200, 200, 1))`. Or maybe I don't understand you.

Comment: @VansFannel you are right. I used the original values of your model just in case somebody else reads this answer.